# If R is partial order on B, then prove R is partial order on $B \times B$

Tags: self-learning, order-theory

Now let $(x,y) \in  B \times B$. So  $x \in B$ and $y \in B$. Since $x,y \in B$ and R is a partial order on $B$ so all conditions on $x$ and $y$ are satisfied. I wonder how to do this ?

Comment: $R$ is a subset of $B \times B$ to be a partial order on $R.$ But a partial order on $B \times B$ would have to be  subset of $(B \times B) \times (B \times B).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is a partial order on $B$, then $S \subseteq B^2 \times B^2$ defined by
$$(a,b) S (c,d) \;\Leftrightarrow\; aRc \,\&\, bRd$$
is a partial order on $B^2$.
This is straightforward to prove.

Of course, as some other user put it in an answer, there is not only one.
Still this one is often seen as the most natural, since given posets $(P_1,\leq_1)$ and $(P_2,\leq_2)$, the direct product is defined as $(P,\leq)$, having $P=P_1\times P_2$ (cartesian product) as its base set, and $\leq$ defined by
$$(p_1,p_2) \leq (q_1,q_2) \;\Leftrightarrow\; p_1 \leq_1 q_1 \,\&\, p_2 \leq_2 q_2.$$
Again, it is straightforward to prove that $(P,\leq)$ thus defined is indeed a poset, and I would recommend you to do this.
Then just consider $(P_1,\leq_1)=(P_2,\leq_2)=(B,R)$, and you have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

$R$ cannot be a partial order on $B \times B$ as a partial order consists of pairs: $R \subseteq B \times B$ but $R \nsubseteq \left(B \times B\right) \times \left(B \times B\right)$.
I think you actually mean something different: "Does $R$ *induce* such a partial order (in a canonical way)"?
Considering $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ might help.

Comment: What do you mean by last line ?

Comment: Well, you can construct partial orders on $\mathbb{C}$ based on the order on $\mathbb{R}$ - but note the plural! These orders are not unique, so in genearal $R$ would not even induce a (canonical) partial order on $B \times B$ without extra conventions. However conventions like that could possibly be designed in the fashion of a lexicographical order (trivial case if $R$ is a total order).